# How to asynchronously call JavaScript in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a flutter web where i have a JavaScript function like this:

```
async function doSomething(value) {
   let x = await something(x);
   return x
}
```

When I'm now in dart, I have:

```
final result = await js.context.callMethod('doSomething', ['someValue']));
```

This returns `[object Promise]` when I print it, but it does ignore `await`, does not have a `.then` function and is therefore not working with `promiseToFuture` either.

How can I wait for JavaScript to be executed?

Comment: Could you share an example promise without a `.then`.

Comment: Also I hope you did do something like `final result = await promiseToFuture(js.context.callMethod('doSomething', ['someValue'])));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a Future builder to wait for JS to execute?

```
Future getSomething(String someValue) async {
  var result = await js.context.callMethod('doSomething', [someValue]));
  return result;
}

FutureBuilder(
        future: getSomething(someValue),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var data = snapshot.data;
            print(data);
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 9):

Just `await` doesn't work for `js.context.callMethod`.

This must be added somewhere in your code, maybe like `javascript_controller.dart`

```
@JS()
library script.js;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'dart:js_util';

@JS()
external dynamic doSomething();
```

and then

```
Future getSomething(String someValue) async {
  var result = await promiseToFuture(doSomething());
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place it in index.html

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

In Script.js

```
async function showAlert(href,hashtag,quote) {
      if (response) {   
      window.dartFunc("asd");
      dartFunc("asd");        
      } else if () {
          alert("error adding points");     
      }
      else{
            alert("error dialog close");
      }
  });
};
```

In your dart file in initstate()

```
setProperty(window, 'dartFunc', js.allowInterop(dartFunc));

sss() async {
 await js.context.callMethod('showAlert', [
      '',
      '',
      ''
    ]);
}

String dartFunc(String str) {
    Common.showToast('Music');
    Common.showToast(str);

    return 'Inside dartFunc: ' + str;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same method to do asynchronously from js file using async and used `--promisetofuture` in dart file but i am unable to wait until we get response from js file for flutter web

```
async function getPhoneNumber() {
    let res = await someFunction to wait for someTime;
    return res;
}

function somfunc() async{
    var number = await 
    promiseToFuture(js.context.callMethod('getPhoneNumber'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is creating a callback on Flutter and then calling it when my method is done.

So on the js script:

```
    async function testAsync(input) {
      var output = await window.test(input); //the async func
      window.flutterCallback(output);
    }


    window.testAsync = testAsync;
```

And on Flutter:

```
@JS()
external dynamic testAsync(String input); //should match js function

@JS('flutterCallback') // should match callback name
external set _flutterCallback(void Function(String output) f);

Completer<String>? _flutterCompleter;

Future<dynamic> callAsyncFunc(String input) async {
  _flutterCallback = allowInterop((output) {
    _flutterCompleter?.complete(output);
  });
  _flutterCompleter = Completer<String>();
  testAsync(jwt);
  return _flutterCompleter?.future;
```